# Excel blank string > number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I am comparing a blank string to a number. I expected it to return an error, but instead it returns true.

Cell `A2` has a value of `""`. When I run

```
=IF(A2>52,"Wrong","Right")
```

I get "Wrong".

I was expecting an error or "Right". Why does Excel think that an empty string is a number?

Comment: For the same reason that "apple">52? Or that "52">52?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formulas/text-is-greater-than-number